# overcome microbursts in cisco router or transmitting linux machine

Tags: cisco, switch, multicast, linux, packet-loss

I have linux machine multicasting UDP streams with Java applications. The multicats go though ciso router. I see lot of packet losses at receivers. Checking ports in routers reveals overruns counter increasing. Searching on internet specifies these happens due to microbursts from TX machine. I also guess same, because drops increases with time, may be java app getting unstable with time, and then starting outputting bursts of packets, its buggy.  Maybe I can change something in the router?

**EDIT**

Following is Cisco hardware:

Cisco WS-C6504-E w/ FAN-MOD-4HS Empty 4-slot 6500 Enhanced Chassis 1

Cisco PWR-2700-AC/4 2700W AC Power for 7604 6504-E #12025 X 2 2

Cisco Catalyst 6500 7600 Supervisor 720 Module - WS-SUP720-3BXL WS-F6K-PFC3BXL 1

Cisco WS-X6548-GE-TX 48-Port 1G Copper Eth Module

Following is CPU utilization:

```
RHE-001#show fabric utilization all
 slot    channel      speed    Ingress %     Egress %
    1          0        20G            0            0
    2          0         8G           12            2
    3          0         8G            9           14
    4          0         8G            0           13

RHE-001#
```

Following is interface statistics:

```
RHE-001#show int GigabitEthernet 2/4
GigabitEthernet2/4 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is C6k 1000Mb 802.3, address is 0023.04dd.0d00 (bia 0023.04dd.0d00)
  Internet address is 10.0.1.13/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 7/255, rxload 21/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseT
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is off
  Clock mode is auto
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:27, output 00:00:05, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 5d08h
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 83389000 bits/sec, 7648 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 30360000 bits/sec, 2786 packets/sec
  L2 Switched: ucast: 32 pkt, 2048 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
  L3 in Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 3542591539 pkt, 4825009676118 bytes mcast
  L3 out Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes mcast: 2879819193 pkt, 3922313740866 bytes
     3542548642 packets input, 4830700273704 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 3542548610 broadcasts (3542458124 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 4243199 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 0 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     1276819687 packets output, 1738995021346 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
RHE-001#
```

As we can see **overrun** counter increasing.

Buffers:

```
RHE-001#show buffers
Buffer elements:
     499 in free list (500 max allowed)
     623919821 hits, 0 misses, 0 created

Public buffer pools:
Small buffers, 104 bytes (total 1024, permanent 1024):
     1021 in free list (128 min, 2048 max allowed)
     183749828 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Medium buffers, 256 bytes (total 3000, permanent 3000):
     2999 in free list (64 min, 3000 max allowed)
     22779465 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Middle buffers, 600 bytes (total 512, permanent 512):
     510 in free list (64 min, 1024 max allowed)
     5814462 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Big buffers, 1536 bytes (total 1000, permanent 1000):
     999 in free list (64 min, 1000 max allowed)
     2009529750 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
VeryBig buffers, 4520 bytes (total 10, permanent 10):
     10 in free list (0 min, 100 max allowed)
     363 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Large buffers, 9240 bytes (total 8, permanent 8):
     8 in free list (0 min, 10 max allowed)
     57 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Huge buffers, 18024 bytes (total 2, permanent 2):
     2 in free list (0 min, 4 max allowed)
     41 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)

Interface buffer pools:
Syslog ED Pool buffers, 600 bytes (total 150, permanent 150):
     118 in free list (150 min, 150 max allowed)
     10421 hits, 10168 misses
LI Middle buffers, 600 bytes (total 512, permanent 256, peak 512 @ 7w0d):
     256 in free list (256 min, 768 max allowed)
     171 hits, 85 fallbacks, 0 trims, 256 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
     256 max cache size, 256 in cache
     0 hits in cache, 0 misses in cache
EOBC0/0 buffers, 1524 bytes (total 2400, permanent 2400):
     1200 in free list (0 min, 2400 max allowed)
     1200 hits, 0 fallbacks
     1200 max cache size, 680 in cache
     2369496864 hits in cache, 0 misses in cache
LI Big buffers, 1536 bytes (total 512, permanent 256, peak 512 @ 7w0d):
     256 in free list (256 min, 768 max allowed)
     171 hits, 85 fallbacks, 0 trims, 256 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
     256 max cache size, 256 in cache
     0 hits in cache, 0 misses in cache
IPC buffers, 4096 bytes (total 2352, permanent 2352):
     2242 in free list (784 min, 7840 max allowed)
     333747144 hits, 0 fallbacks, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
LI Very Big buffers, 4520 bytes (total 257, permanent 128, peak 257 @ 7w0d):
     129 in free list (128 min, 384 max allowed)
     85 hits, 43 fallbacks, 4101 trims, 4230 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
     128 max cache size, 128 in cache
     0 hits in cache, 0 misses in cache
Private Huge IPC buffers, 18024 bytes (total 2, permanent 2):
     2 in free list (1 min, 4 max allowed)
     0 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)
Private Huge buffers, 65280 bytes (total 2, permanent 2):
     2 in free list (1 min, 4 max allowed)
     787 hits, 0 misses, 0 trims, 0 created
     0 failures (0 no memory)

Header pools:


RHE-001#
```

**EDIT 2**

There are no switches. The multicast transmitting machines and receiving machines are directly connected to cisco router.

Comment: @MikePennington thanks for edit. I will retrieve more information and will post it.

Comment: We'll need to know the hardware in use, and their configurations. Multicast routing can be tricky, and low-end devices will be very limiting. (I use a linux router, and it's multicast routing is specifically limited to 50kbps -- ntp is all that's intended to flow through it.)

Comment: You could look into using [Flow Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control).  It would have to be supported by both the Switch and the Host that is sending the microbursts.  It allows the Switch to instruct the Host to temporarily pause (XOFF) transmission if the switch buffers are nearing capacity, and then once the Switch has forwarded frames and made more room in its buffer, the switch can send an XON to the host to have it continue sending packets.  It effectively allows a smarter use of the switch's input buffer and rx rings.

Comment: Hi All, I have updated question. Can you please guide me in right direction.

Comment: @Eddie will Flow Control be fast enough to pause sending host microburst?

Comment: @UDPLover, it's possible that flow-control is sufficient.  Sadly, you haven't given us any configurations from the switch; nor do we have a diagram of the network so this question is a bit challenging to help with.  If flow-control isn't sufficient, please consider adding [more details](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist)

Comment: @MikePennington There are no switches in network. All machines are directly connected to router.

Comment: Sup720-3BXL *is* a switch

Comment: I am not cisco expert. :( But I know machines are directly connected to router.

Comment: @MikePennington sorry, line card is 6548 GE-TX, not 6848.

Comment: Yes this is switch. We have all UDP multicasts, L3 switched, because every host connected to it is in different subnets. IP addresses of all hosts connected has 30 bit network addresses.

Comment: Looks like I have overrun issue as mentioned in this: https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/71201/switch-fabric-troubleshooting-tips at bottom of article. We have not more than 500 Mbps usage per 8-port slots, but may be microbursts overutilizing for short micro-milli seconds and we see overruns. Will try to rearrange all ports according to bandwidth usages and will post here if it resolves.

Comment: it's certainly possible that you have overruns from port-asic oversubscription.  How many different ports are subscribed to your multicast application?  What is the smallest IP packet size your application sends?  What IOS version are you running?

Comment: @MikePennington I have total around 100 hosts connected to 3 slots. Some only receive, some only transmit and some do both. Some do RX as low as 5 Mbps, and as high as 400 Mbps. Some do TX as low as 5 Mbps and TX as high as 400 Mbps. All mulicasts has UDP payload of constant size 1316 bytes. We have around 99% network used by these multicasts only. We run IOS 12. Total input to switch is around 2 Gbps and output around 3 Gbps.

Comment: @MikePennington We have no any 8 ports oversubscribed, and we dont see usual packet losses. But I think sometime some micro-milli seconds bursts doing over-subscription and we do see bunch of packet losses on analyzers at unknown times. These all multicasts are kind of video streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first of all `show fabric utilization all` shows fabric utilization, not CPU utilization. Fabric doesn't have CPU component per se, and you can go all up to 100% of fabric utilization without any adverse effects similar to what CPU causes when nearing to the full load.

Next, the **WS-X6548-GE-TX is 8Gbit/s card**, so "old" fabric attached LC with 8Gbit/s channel. Internally, it shares buffers per 8 ports on card, so given you're getting 'overrun' errors that typically point to a problem with receiving traffic in timely manner and handing it over to other ports, first thing I'd do is separate incoming 8-port group on the card to separate group. In other words, if there is specific port/group of ports receiving high-volume multicast traffic, I'd move it to separate group on the card - and please rememeber, each consecutive 8 ports is one "group":

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/hardware/Module_Installation/Mod_Install_Guide/6500-emig/02ethern.html#wp1043307

This means, among other things, that the 8Gbit/s interface to fabric is statically sliced in 6 groups of 8 ports, out of which each group gets 1Gbit/s maximum. So, if in any given port group (of 8x 10/100/1000 ports) you have ports receiving traffic over 1Gbit/s you'll hit exactly problems you're encountering. That's why my proposal is to move any other ports out of the 8-port group apart from the one interface receiving massive amounts of multicast traffic (it seems it's `GigabitEthernet 2/4` in your case). You can find this information literally stated in the release notes:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/15-1SY/release_notes.html#pgfId-4909956

> The aggregate bandwidth of each set of 8 ports (1–8, 9–16, 17–24,
>   25–32, 33–40, and 41–48) is 1 Gbps."

For better utilization of the physical ports, I'd recommend you take a look at the **WS-X6748-GE-TX** card, that also has 48 10/100/1000 ports but has also **two 20Gbit/s fabric connections**. Those 20Gbit/s fabric channels are split between ports 1-24 and 25-48, so you get still oversubscription, but only 24Gbit/s over the 20Gbit/s supported by channel, not 8Gbit/s over 1Gbit/s as in 6548 (so, effectively, 1.2:1 oversubscription in 6748 vs 8:1 in 6548). This should give you space to burst traffic over the link from the sending station and distribute it across the system.

Comment: thanks for great answer. Does 1 Gbps per 8 ports is combined (TX + RX to fabric from 8 ports) bandwidth, or separate 1 Gbps TX and 1 Gbps RX on 8 port group.

Comment: I have one 6848-tx-2t linecard, can I mix one 6848 and two 6548 cards? Will then 6848 will get connected with two 20 Gbps channels to fabric?

Comment: As for 65xx LCs - it's 1Gbit/s FD, so 1Gbit/s TX and 1Gbit/s RX. The 6848-TX-2T is essentially 6748 with the DFC4, so new-generation distributed forwarding card. The architecture stays the same, so you still have two channels with 20Gbit/s FD per channel.

Comment: Is 6848-TX-2T supported with sup720? I think its not supported, but not sure. sup720 is not detecting 6848-TX-2T.

Comment: Sure, to use anything with PFC4/DFC4 you need compatible PFC on the Supervisor. Sup720 uses PFC3, so older generation policy feature card. You need Sup2T to use anything with DFC4. You can "downgrade" 6868-TX-2T by removing DFC4 and installing CFC in it's place to 6748-TX, you need however to have the CFC. Without CFC the LC won't boot.